# What is the correct syntax for this line of code?

Tags: python-3.x

```
y_series1 = [(z/(roe * g * B * (x ** 2)))
             for z in Fh and for x in x_series]
```

I have assigned `roe`, `g`, `B` values and `z` and `x_series` are lists.

Comment: Please provide example data for the variables.

Comment: `[(z/(roe * g * B * (x ** 2))) for z in Fh for x in x_series]` (without the `and`) is valid Python syntax. Whether it makes sense or not for your particular variables and needs is another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are trying to accomplish with your code:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> roe, g, B = 1, 2, 3
>>> Fh, x_series = range(10, 20), range(20, 30)
>>> y_series_1 = [z / (roe * g * B * x ** 2) for z, x in zip(Fh, x_series)]
>>> len(y_series_1)
10
>>>
```

In order to pull values from both `Fh` and `x_series`, you should `zip` the two together. If you want your code to run faster, replace the creation of `y_series_1` with the following two lines instead:

```
>>> product = roe * g * B
>>> y_series_1 = [z / (product * x * x) for z, x in zip(Fh, x_series)]
```

Comment: Thank you I was looking for the (for z, x in zip(Fh, x_series) bit

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear because there are two possible interpretations of your pseudocode:

1. If `Fh` and `x_series` are lists of elements that correspond to each other by index, you can do a single loop that takes one element from each list using `zip`:

   ```
   y_series1 = [(z/(roe * g * B * (x ** 2))) for z, x in zip(Fh, x_series)]
   ```

   The result will be the same length as the shorter of `Fh` and `x_series`, although ideally they will be the same length in this case.
2. You want to match each element of one list to each element of the other. This is basically like running a nested loop. You can make the result 1D like this:

   ```
   y_series1 = [(z/(roe * g * B * (x ** 2))) for z in Fh for x in x_series]
   ```

   The result will have `len(Fh) * len(x_series)` elements. To make a 2D array, include another set of brackets:

   ```
   y_series1 = [[(z/(roe * g * B * (x ** 2))) for z in Fh] for x in x_series]
   ```

   This way, the result will be a `len(x_series)` list containing `len(Fh)` sub-lists in every element.

Comment: Thank you yes number one was what I was looking for.